# C - Subtraction of numbers with many decimals

Tags: c

Why does the C code below output "Difference: 0.000000" ? I need to make calculations with many decimals in one of my university tasks and I don't understand this because I'm new to programming in C. Am I using the correct type? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int main() {

long double a = 1.00000001;
long double b = 1.00000000;
long double difference = a-b;

printf("Difference: %Lf", difference);

}
```

I have tried that code and I'm expecting to get the result: "Difference: 0.00000001"

Comment: Try `printf("Difference: %.20Lf", difference);` instead. Then read [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see `0.000000` because `%Lf` prints a fixed number of decimal places, and the default number is 6.  In your case, the difference is 1 in the 8<sup>th</sup> decimal place, which shows as `0.000000` when printed to 6 d.p.  Either use `%Le` or `%Lg` or specify more precision: `%.8Lf`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long double a = 1.00000001;
    long double b = 1.00000000;
    long double difference = a - b;

    printf("Difference: %Lf\n", difference);
    printf("Difference: %.8Lf\n", difference);
    printf("Difference: %Le\n", difference);
    printf("Difference: %Lg\n", difference);
    return 0;
}
```

Note the minimal set of headers.

Output:

```
Difference: 0.000000
Difference: 0.00000001
Difference: 1.000000e-08
Difference: 1e-08
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    long double a = 1.000000001;
    long double b = 1.000000000;
    long double difference = a-b;
    
    printf("Difference: %.9Lf\n", difference);

}
```

Try this code.  Actually, you need to specify to the compiler how much precision you need after the decimal point.  Here the `.9` will print 9 digits after the decimal point.  You can adjust this value according to your needs; just don't exceed the range of the variable.